# sshポートフォワーディングで、localに転送する際に、localの指定のパスに転送したい。

Tags: ssh

こちらのページを参照し、sshポートフォワーディングについてはおおよそ理解しました。

http://komaken.me/blog/2014/05/23/ssh-remote-forward%E3%82%92%E5%88%A9%E7%94%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E5%A4%96%E9%83%A8%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90%E3%81%AE%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AF%E3%82%A8%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%82%92%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AB/

グローバルアドレスをもった、EC2インスタンス（仮にexample.com:9876）に対し、アクセスを行った際に、
localで起動しているサーバー(localhost:80)に転送をさせたいです。

```
※ 実際にはまだドメインをもっていないため
EC２作成時にできるパブリック DNSであるこちらを使用しております。
ec2-<IPアドレス>.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

ただ、今回は、example.com/sample/hoge というURLに対してGETのリクエストが来たときに、localhost/sample/hoge のURLに転送をしてほしいです。

`ssh -R 80:example.com:9876 username@example.com`

これらをふまえてわからない点が2点御座います。

1) 上記コマンドでsshしたあと、curlした際に、port 9876: 接続を拒否されましたと表示されます。
   尚、該当のEC2のセキュリティグループでは、ポートを開放しております。

`curl example.com:9876 -X GET`

```
カスタム TCP ルール(タイプ)
TCP(プロトコル)
9876(ポート)
0.0.0.0/0(送信元)
```

2) また、質問1では、パス指定をしておりませんが、前述のlocalの指定のパスに転送するという方法についてがわかりません。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 状況から察するに、`ssh -R 9876:localhost:80 username@example.com` とするのではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

(1)については、コメントにも書いてありますが、`ssh -R 9876:localhost:80 username@example.com`が正しいコマンドです。これでexample.com:9879へのアクセスがsshを実行しているPCのポート80に転送されます。
詳しくは[この記事](http://qiita.com/mechamogera/items/b1bb9130273deb9426f5#%E3%83%AA%E3%83%A2%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%AF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89)を参照してください。
なお、example.comのサーバ(EC2インスタンス)のsshd_config(`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`)に`GatewayPorts yes`を書いておく必要があると思います。ssh_configと間違えないように気を付けてください。

(2)については何もすることはありません。sshが転送するのはトランスポート層の話で、HTTPリクエストのパスの部分はその上の層のデータなので、そのまま転送されるはずです。